# How to fix cursor and icon display size issues for 4k display?

Tags: gnome, gtk, qt, cursor, 4k-monitor

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 on a 4k display. In general, things look fine in the GNOME shell. However, some GTK/Qt applications still have trouble displaying properly, including:

- mouse cursor size
- UI icon size
- font sizes

[image: QGIS with large cursor]
[image: QGIS with small cursor]
[image: GIMP with large cursor]
[image: GIMP with small cursor]

How can I configure Qt/GTK-based applications to properly inherit system display settings?

Comment: Could you try launching an app using this environment variable as follows `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1 command_to_launch_app` and see if that helps?

Comment: I set the `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1` in `.bashrc`, but the problem persists.

Comment: Could you see if setting it to '0' makes a difference `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`?